# how to make a redirect link if the href attribute is not what you want

Tags: javascript, html

I tried but it didn't work because my ability in javascript is almost zero

```
var element = document.getElementById("change");
var going = "https://google.com";

if (typeof (element) == 'undefined' && element == null) {
  window.location.replace((going));
}
else if (typeof (element).attr(href) != 'https://google.com') {
  window.location.replace((going));
}
```

I want if #change does not exist then the page will redirect, but if there is but the href attribute is not what you want then the page will also redirect.
It is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="id">
<head></head>
<body>
<footer>
  <div class="credit-link">
    Template By <a  class="change" id="change" title="Google" href='https://google.com'>Google</a>
  </div>
</footer>
<script src="js/copy.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a id='change' href='https://google.com'></a>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("change");
var going = "https://google.com";

if (element == undefined) { //if the element does not exist
  window.location.replace(going);
}
else if (element.href != 'https://google.com/') { //if the element href is not https://google.com
  window.location.replace(going);
}
</script>
```

Comment: for the first if there is no problem. but for else if it doesn't work properly, even though I added the attribute `href="https://google.com"`

Comment: My mistake, I had misspelled the URL in the else if statement. I've edited it and it should work now.

Comment: still redirects even if the attribute is `https://google.com`

Comment: I'm assuming the href of `element` is `https://www.google.com`

Comment: keep redirecting even though the attribute `https://google.com` or `https://google.com/`

Comment: I've added the HTML with it so you can see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your objective clearly but as I understand that

- you want to redirect page if there is no element with `#change` id the page should redirect.
- if the element is existing but the link is not the same as we want then redirect to a specific location.
  Am I right.

I am assuming that you want to redirect to `https://google.com`,

first of all, you have to prevent the redirection of the link using js, there are two ways

1. `<a id="logout-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Logout</a>` but this will not work for you because you want to have a link in `href`.
2. you have to prevent the redirection of href link using `event.preventDefault();` funtion.

Then your code should look like

```js
var element = document.getElementById("change");
var going = "https://google.com";

element.addEventListener( "click", (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
//.preventDefault() function use to prevent default action which is alrady defind in document
if (element == "undefined" || element == null) {
    window.location.assign(going);
} else if (element.href != "https://google.com") {
    // you can also use element.getAttribute('href')
    window.location.assign(going);
    //you user .replace insted of assing  which is use to replace string in the string.
 }
},  false );
```

> use used some function a `typeof` use to get which type of variable is. its value could be `String`, `number`, etc......,

I hope that will help you

HAPPY CODING :)

Comment: Your understanding is correct, sorry about my question because I use google translate :D. Your answer looks good but it's too complicated for me, don't forget I have almost zero javascript knowledge. Thanks for the answer but I have succeeded by @alexanderbira answer.